# What is the code to use google analytics in seperate .js file?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I read somewhere that placing google analytics tracking code in seperate file is not recommended but I have no idea how to use it for my website (there are .php files and .tpl files and if I tried to put it almost everywhere and there was an error or it didn`t track the visitors).

Could anyone tell me which code I should put into separate **.js file** and in **.tpl file** so at least the basic functions would work? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the cleanest (using a anonymous auto-executing function):

```
(function() {
    var _gaq = window._gaq = window._gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Then reference in either your head or before end of body via:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR_GA_CODE_LOCATION.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write google analytics code in separate js file and include that js and call its function -

Suppose, following code is written in mygoogle.js

```
function loadMyGoogle()
window._gaq = window._gaq || [];
    window._gaq.push([ '_setAccount',
            'setaccounthere']);
(function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl'
                : 'http://www')
                + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
}
```

then in your php files in header -

```
<head>
<include script="mygoogle.js">
</head>
```

In onload function of body tag -

```
function onload(){
loadMyGoogle();
}
```

I hope you know how you can set onload event in body tag

Answer (score 0):

Do not put GA code in .js file instead include html page.

Steps: 
1) Open notepad and paste GA code there.
2) Save it as HTML page
3) Include that html before end of head tag